# Spring JMS message converter for DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: jms, spring-jms

The `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` class in spring JMS has the setter method
`setMessageConverter(...)` which allows to supply any converter we want.

For an annotated message listener, this makes sense as we can directly define

```
@JmsListener(destination = "myDestination")
public void processOrder(MyConvertedType data) { ... }
```

and spring will take care of converting and passing the message to this listener.

So, this clearly makes sense for an annotated listener. My question is, is setting a message converter useful for non-annotated message listeners? Something like

```
public void registerListener(String queueName, MessageListener listener) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setMessageConverter(getMessageConverter());
        container.setDestinationName(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listener);
        container.initialize();
        container.start();
}
```

From my search in the docs/javadocs and the limited understanding of source code, I think that setting a message converter for this case is not helpful, i.e. message conversion will not handled by spring. The conversion has to be handled in the passed MessageListener callback? Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used only when the container is created to support a `@JmsListener` annotation - the converter is transferred from the container factory to the container, and thence to the `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter` which is used to invoke the annotated POJO method.

The container is just a conduit to configure the adapter via the container factory.

So, yes, it's ignored for a simple `MessageListener`.

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's too hard to read; and don't ask new questions in comments on 3+ year old answers. Ask a new question and format your code appropriately.

Comment: Agree. Thanks for the heads up. Will write a questions instead.